# Unable to insert a record into MySQL database using DBI

Tags: mysql, perl, cgi, dbi

I am trying to insert a record into a MySQL database using Perl DBI. I am not getting any errors but the insert is not working. However, I am able to successfully fetch records from the database using DBI.

Here is the code that does the insert:

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

use diagnostics;
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $driver = "mysql"; 
my $database = "mysql";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
my $userid = "root";
my $password = "password";

my $buffer;
my @pairs;
my $pair;
my $name;
my $value;
my %FORM;

# Read in text
my $ENV;
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "GET")
{
    $buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
}

# Split information into name/value pairs
@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
foreach $pair (@pairs)
{
    ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
    $value =~ tr/+/ /;
    $value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
    $FORM{$name} = $value;
}

my $first_name= $FORM{name};
my $address = $FORM{address};
my $city  = $FORM{city};
my $occupation  = $FORM{occupation};
my $age  = $FORM{age};

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:dbname=mysql", "root", "password",{ AutoCommit =>  0,RaiseError => 1}, ) or die ("Couldn't connect to database: ") , $DBI::errstr;

# my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO persons
                        # (FirstName, LastName,Address,City)
                        # values
                        # ($first_name, $last_name,$address,$city)");
my $query = "insert into userrecords(Address,Age,City,Name,Occupation)
             values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";

my $statement = $dbh->prepare($query) or die ("Couldn't connect to database: "), $DBI::errstr;
$statement->execute($address,$age,$city,$name,$occupation) or die ("Couldn't connect to database: "), $DBI::errstr;

$dbh->disconnect();

my $URL = "http://.....:81/cgi-bin/showdata.cgi";
print "Location: $URL\n\n";

exit(0);
```

When I run my code in the Padre IDE, I get the following errors:

```
****Error*********
Useless use of a variable in void context at InsertRecord.cgi line 50 (#1)
    (W void) You did something without a side effect in a context that does
    nothing with the return value, such as a statement that doesn't return a
    value from a block, or the left side of a scalar comma operator.  Very
    often this points not to stupidity on your part, but a failure of Perl
    to parse your program the way you thought it would.  For example, you'd
    get this if you mixed up your C precedence with Python precedence and
    said

        $one, $two = 1, 2;

    when you meant to say

        ($one, $two) = (1, 2);

    Another common error is to use ordinary parentheses to construct a list
    reference when you should be using square or curly brackets, for
    example, if you say

        $array = (1,2);

    when you should have said

        $array = [1,2];

    The square brackets explicitly turn a list value into a scalar value,
    while parentheses do not.  So when a parenthesized list is evaluated in
    a scalar context, the comma is treated like C's comma operator, which
    throws away the left argument, which is not what you want.  See
    perlref for more on this.

    This warning will not be issued for numerical constants equal to 0 or 1
    since they are often used in statements like

        1 while sub_with_side_effects();

    String constants that would normally evaluate to 0 or 1 are warned
    about.

Useless use of a variable in void context at InsertRecord.cgi line 59 (#1)
Useless use of a variable in void context at InsertRecord.cgi line 60 (#1)

Use of uninitialized value in transliteration (tr///) at InsertRecord.cgi line
        23 (#2)
    (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
    defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
    To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.

    To help you figure out what was undefined, perl will try to tell you the
    name of the variable (if any) that was undefined. In some cases it cannot
    do this, so it also tells you what operation you used the undefined value
    in.  Note, however, that perl optimizes your program and the operation
    displayed in the warning may not necessarily appear literally in your
    program.  For example, "that $foo" is usually optimized into "that "
    . $foo, and the warning will refer to the concatenation (.) operator,
    even though there is no . in your program.

Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"} in string eq at
        InsertRecord.cgi line 24 (#2)
Use of uninitialized value $buffer in split at InsertRecord.cgi line 29 (#2)
Location: http://.......:81/cgi-bin/showdata.cgi

Press any key to continue . . .

***********END***********************
```

What is the issue?

Comment: there should be an error when insert fails.

Comment: Please check the added error!!!

Comment: Do you think that `my $ENV` and `$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'}` refers to the same variable? Because it does not `%ENV` is a predefined hash that contains your environment variables.

Comment: your script completes so row is inserted into table. btw, consider `CGI` module instead of manual form parameter parsing.

Comment: @TLP Is "$ENV" the problem? I am getting name,age etc from querystring. So i guess it is used to fetch querystring data.

Comment: @mpapec Row is not getting inserted..could you please help where i am getting wrong?

Comment: try basic debugging, output valid html header followed by `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper [$address,$age,$city,$name,$occupation]`

Comment: There is not at all any issue in getting these variables. As i have tried to print it in a HTML and that is giving me fine result. Is it because of any configuration issue in DBI?

Comment: @user3181823 No, you got an uninitialized warning about `$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'}` and `$buffer`, so you did not get name, age etc from it.

Comment: @TLP it seems that these warnings are from Padre IDE, but more/less fine in web server.

Comment: But why any record isn't get inserted while it can easily fetch the records.

Comment: you might be inserting in wrong mysql server/database/table.

Comment: same table/server/database used as used for Get records. No issues in that either.

Comment: @user3181823 This code of yours is very hard to read. You should remove useless things, like blank or commented out lines, use proper indentation and at the very least make sure your lines line up.

Comment: On that note, you are not using `my` correctly when you declare all variables at the top of the script. You should use them in the smallest scope possible, *at the place in the code they are used*, such as `foreach my $pair (...)`. When declaring multiple variables, you can group them, like so: `my ($foo, @bar, %baz)` to avoid spam.

Comment: The data is almost certainly being inserted correctly. But without a call to `commit`, the insertion is being rolled-back when the transaction ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you replace your code with this:

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
use strict;
use warnings;

use diagnostics;
use DBI;
use CGI qw[param redirect];    

my $driver   = "mysql"; 
my $database = "mysql";
my $dsn      = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
my $userid   = "root";
my $password = "password";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:dbname=mysql", "root", "password",
    { AutoCommit =>  0,RaiseError => 1}, )
    or die "Couldn't connect to database: ", $DBI::errstr;

my $query = "insert into userrecords(Address,Age,City,Name,Occupation)
values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";

my $statement = $dbh->prepare($query)
    or die "Couldn't connect to database: " , $DBI::errstr;
$statement->execute(param('address'), param('age'), param('city'),
                    param('name'), param('occupation'))
    or die "Couldn't connect to database: " , $DBI::errstr;    
$dbh->disconnect();

my $URL = "http://.....:81/cgi-bin/showdata.cgi";
print redirect($URL);
```

I've basically made two changes:

1. Use the CGI.pm module to handle the CGI interaction (getting the parameters and printing the redirection header).
2. Fixed your "void context" errors by removing the misplaced parentheses in all of your calls to `die`.

I'm made no substantive changes to the code, but at least we now have a clean version to go with.

**Update:** D'oh. It's obvious now the code is cleaned up a bit. If you have "Autocommit" turned off, then you need to commit your changes. Add `$dbh->commit` between the calls to `execute()` and `disconnect()`.

Answer (score 2):

When I was editing your code so that it was more readable, I stumbled upon what I assume is the solution:

You are using `$name` when inserting into the database, but you use `$first_name` when getting the value `$FORM{name}`. So since you used `$name` above, it has the value of the last name used, whatever that might be. The relevant code snippets:

```
($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
...
$FORM{$name} = $value;
...
my $first_name = $FORM{name};
...
$statement->execute($address,$age,$city,$name,$occupation)
#                                       ^^^^^--- should be $first_name
```

Your problem would have been solved if you had used proper scope on your variables, namely something like this:

```
 foreach my $pair (@pairs) {
     my ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
     $value =~ tr/+/ /;
     $value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
     $FORM{$name} = $value;
 }
```

Then when you later would try to use `$name`, you would get the error

```
Global variable "$name" requires explicit package name ...
```

Which would alert you to your mistake and save you hours in debugging time. When you declare variables at the top of the script, instead of in the smallest possible scope, you effectively disable the protection that `use strict 'vars'` offers. So don't do that.

Also, you should probably use the [`CGI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) module instead of trying to handle it manually. It will make things easier, and safer. Don't forget to perform sanity checks on your data to prevent database injection attacks.

Your script when cleaned up and properly formatted looks like [this.](http://pastebin.com/WuSSKJUM)

Answer (score 1):

The warning comes from this:

```
or die ("Couldn't connect to database: ") , $DBI::errstr;
```

The `, $DBI::errstr` is outside of the die and nothing is done with it, thus being in void context. You want something like this:

```
or die ("Couldn't connect to database:  $DBI::errstr");
```

Also, your form handling code has some issues. If you're writing CGI scripts, you may as well use the `CGI` module. Here's a quick cleanup of your code:

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
use diagnostics;
use CGI ':standard';
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $driver   = "mysql";
my $database = "mysql";
my $dsn      = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
my $userid   = "root";
my $password = "password";

my $name       = param('name');
my $address    = param('address');
my $city       = param('city');
my $occupation = param('occupation');
my $age        = param('age');

my $dbh = DBI->connect( $dsn, $userid, $password,
    { AutoCommit => 1, RaiseError => 1 },
) or die("Couldn't connect to database: $DBI::errstr");

my $query = <<'END';
INSERT INTO userrecords(Address,Age,City,Name,Occupation)
                VALUES (      ?,   ?,  ?,    ?,        ?)
END

my $statement = $dbh->prepare($query);
$statement->execute( $address, $age, $city, $name, $occupation );
$dbh->disconnect();

my $URL = "http://.....:81/cgi-bin/showdata.cgi";
print "Location: $URL\n\n";
```

Note that I've removed many `or die` statements because you already have `RaiseError` set to a true value.

For simplicity's sake, I've also (reluctantly) turned on `AutoCommit`.